# Get the objectId of a newly saved PFObject

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am using latest Parse SDK and am sending data to the Cloud Data.
This is my code at the moment but am unsure how to retrieve the objectId upon success:

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"CLASS_NAME"];
testObject[@"Name"] = firstName;
testObject[@"LastName"] = lastName;

[testObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) 
{
    if (succeeded) 
    {
        //success trigger
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its inside:

```
PFObject *testObject
```

access it with

```
NSLog(@"objectID: %@", testObject.objectId);
```

see: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectId